# Re-showing Push Notification Popup after App Update

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

is there a way to re-show the iOS Push Notification User Permission dialog after a user choose to not allow PNs for the app?

Consider this example:

1. User installs app, get PN permission popup, chooses No.
2. App wont use PNs and wont ask again for permission.
3. We release an update with a new feature related to PNs and want to re-show the PN permission dialog again to the user after he updated.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I uprooted this question a few hours ago. Disappointed nobody commented, so I'll try. There are two info.plist keys I need to add because of permission popups about using the camera app and the camera roll (but probably very different from a PN). I was thinking about two things - being very unaware of how the PN permission is asked for. (1) Any user can simply uninstall/reinstall and (I think) the PN popup has to happen, Can you do something to have the OS believe that? (2) If my required popup is from info.plist, can you make an "inconsequential" that would bring this up?

Comment: @dfd Thanks for upvoting! so far I haven't found any other info on whether this is possible or not and it seems there isn't much request from other devs to have this. So I take it that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue in the following manner:

1. First time user declines notification pop-up shown.
2. After that every time user comes to a specific page you can check if the notification for the app is ON
3. Use following code to check if notifications is ON:

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]
   ```
4. If you detect push notification is OFF, prompt the user to settings page using:

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
   ```

Let me know if you have additional question

Comment: Thank you @FelixSFD for updating the format. I am new to using stackoverflow.